# Is "google.script.run" part of javascript specs?

Tags: google-apps-script

I don't understand how the `google.script.run` statement can be understood by the javascript on the client's browser. Is it part of the javascript specifications like for example the `alert()` or anything else that browser's javascript engine understand?

Comment: No. I don't think so. I believe it's injected by Google whenever html is served.

Comment: `google.script.run` is called a "Client-side API" by Apps Script.  `google` is not a native JavaScript class, it's specific to HTML created by Apps Script with the `HTML Service`.  The `google.script.run` code must be written in JavaScript, and be in the browser somewhere, but I don't know how you access it.  Any function names in your ".gs" Apps Script files that you want hidden, should end with an underbar.  `function myPrivateFunctionName_() {//some code;}`

Comment: According to the previous comments, I can conclude that this command can be seen as is stored on the google but when it passes through the HTMLService google converts it into the corresponding client javasrcipt commands (like Ajax) so that the cilent's browser can run javascript commands that recognize them!! As a result if we search the source code of the html page on the client we will not find any "google.script.run" statement. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

No.  It's injected by Google whenever html is served through `HtmlService`